# CollisionDetection of manual scaling Object (2D) in Unity 5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, game-physics

#### Overview of Game:

The main character of the game is a gum which throws a piece of itself which is called anchor in any direction or at any angle.

There is a thread like connection, which is called connection-thread Object, between the gum and its anchors whose elastic structure is implemented using SpringJoin2D which gives the connection-thread a spring-like behavior.

In order to make the connection-thread more dynamic, a mechanism is added to the game which lets the connection-thread to get segmented by adding a new anchor in the part of the connection-thread that collides with an object in the game environment. In other words whenever an object hits the connection-thread a static anchor is added in the collision point.

#### The main problem:

The connection-thread Object is scaled and positioned manually in the script, which causes dysfunction in the collision detection system(Box2D) in a way that the collision points cannot be detected correctly.

#### Used Methods :

`boxCollider` / `EdgeCollider` -> dysfunctioned when scaling

`RayCast2D` / `LineCast2D` -> middle anchors enter the environment Object in high speed

static `boxcollider2D` in child object in size of maximum length of connection-thread Object -> [not implemented yet]

Any idea to fix this ?

[image: segmenting connection-thread (normal state)]

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, with kinematic objects you can only have trigger events which only return colliders and not collision information.

I think you may try to check the collision with triggers and then do a circle sweep test in 8 direction for example to search for a collision and receive the information with the raycasthit2D. The sweep test will return you a raycasthit2D wich have a "point" member you can use.

Follow this links -

Unity Manual
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.CircleCast.html

How Capsule and Sphere Cast work (same thing as circle cast but in 3D)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D1xqen8uH64

Hope I could explain myself well enough. Good luck